# Magento 2.0.2 to magento 2.0.7 upgrade fail during readiness check

Tags: upgrade, magento-2.0.2, version

I search on google but not getting any proper solution. Does anyone has any solution for this ?
I am getting this error from admin panel while readiness check for upgrade magento 2.0.7 version.

[image]

Comment: How did you perform the update (update steps)?

Comment: I entered public key and private key then go to system > web setup wizard > system upgrade then check for readiness and throw error which is mentioned in image

Comment: Those type of problems are most probably related to a not correct configuration of the server. Click in show details and try to post here or search with google those types of problems.

Comment: When I update my version of magento I use always composer, like  shown here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98332/how-to-update-magento2-using-composer . But not remove  vendor folder rename it, so you can eventually use it again. Make a copy also of your composer.json for security.

Comment: i changed image plz check question

Comment: try to see here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html for the cron and here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html for php problems and configuration

Comment: Here is your answer. if not! ask more to help you more http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109104/magento2-upgrade-readiness-check-fails-and-uses-system-php-instead-of-webserve

Comment: have you seen this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/tech_bull_207-upgrade.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite user friendly and is saying to set cron job on server. Set below to execute after every 5 minutes on server

php yourMagentoPath/bin/magento cron:run

And perform the check again.

[Cause] :- To upgrade Magento it is must to set a cron job unless you are upgrading using composer. There are many other rediness checks that will only be performed once this cron is set. Try this once and share if it worked.

Apart from this the better way to upgrade Magento is to use composer. Its easy to upgrade using this method and it take less time(Never run composer as root user). By using this method roll-back is also very easy just make sure you have backup of your database as check this [issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120098/magento2-how-to-downgrade-properly/120100#120100).

Answer (score 0):

follow this steps

1. php version must be below

   PHP 7.0.2–7.0.6 except for 7.0.5, 5.6.x or 5.5.x **(PHP 5.4 is not supported)**
2. please ask to your service provider that in apache modules **rewrite_module** is enabled or not? if not than please enable it