# Expoarting all products from backend

Tags: product, export

We have more than 40,000 products with attributes.When i tried to export from backend it throws an error 502 gateway error.Can you please suggest me one solution

Comment: check once : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209033/502-bad-gateway-ngnix-for-magento-application

Comment: thanks for the reply.But for me the site is working proerly when i tried to export the products from backend as CSV then i am getting the error.

Comment: okay, follow the above link once.....

Comment: Thanks I understood from the above link there is solution.To where i created that.ini file and place the code .Please reply me it is bit urgent

Comment: in root of the site, there will be `php.ini` file will be there..... you need to add he code there..... `please take backup of that file before editing` , if `php.ini` file is not there means, there will be `php.ini.sample` file will be there, rename that to `php.ini` and follow the instructions mentioned in that link..... if still issue didt resolved, than contact `hosting team`.....

Comment: did you got solution ?

Comment: no it has lots of issues,we are still struggling.I wanted to ask you one thing is this good when we are downgrading from 2 o 1.9

Comment: i dont have much idea on that. may be you can ask new question once, also check these [link1](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120098/magento2-how-to-downgrade-properly)

& [link2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163014/how-to-downgrade-magento-2-to-magento-1/163016) once....