# Magento2 - Downgrade Magento from 2.3.4 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to downgrade `Magento` from `2.3.4` to `2.3.3`?

Because upon downgrade, It's giving me an error like LayoutProcessor not found and Every page is breaking.

So what's the correct way to do it?

Comment: you use this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120098/magento2-how-to-downgrade-properly

Comment: Is it possible to rollback DB as well without copying?